# Create Pie Chart using data extracted from Firebase Firestore in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pie-chart

I am looking to create a pie chart using data that is stored in Firebase Firestore. I am currently using the MPAndroidChart library which I've got working with a static ArrayList.

```
 ArrayList<PieEntry> hours = new ArrayList<>();

    hours.add(new PieEntry(2, "Professional"));
    hours.add(new PieEntry(1, "Self-Directed"));
    hours.add(new PieEntry(5, "Work-Based Learning"));
    hours.add(new PieEntry(2, "Other"));
```

pie chart static data example

[image]

I want my pie chart to display the total hours/mins completed per activity type (as per image).

My data is organised like this.

[image]

So far, I have been able to extract the overall total hours using the following code and the log is showing the expected answer.

```
CollectionReference cpdHours = fStore.collection("cpdActivities")
            .document(user.getUid())
            .collection("myCPD");

    cpdHours.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                  float totalHours = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                    String sHour = document.getString("Activity_Hours");
                    float xHours = Float.parseFloat(sHour);
                    totalHours += xHours;
                }
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(totalHours));
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to query the data for each different activity type and calculate the total for each type, and then add this information to the ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the activities's name, you can use the Query https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

```java
CollectionReference cpdHoursSelfDirectedLearning = fStore.collection("cpdActivities")
            .document(user.getUid())
            .collection("myCPD");
            .whereEqualTo("Activity_Hours", "Self-Directed Learning")
```

```java
private float calcTime(List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents){
   float totalHours = 0.0;
   for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
     String sHour = document.getString("Activity_Hours");
     float xHours = Float.parseFloat(sHour);
     totalHours += xHours;
   }
   return totalHours
}
```

```java
cpdHoursSelfDirectedLearning.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
               hours.add(
                 new PieEntry(calcTime(task.getResult()), "Self-Directed Learning")
               );
            }
         }
})
```

You have to create an CollectionReference for each activityType (so you have to know the activities type)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've had to make a few tweaks to the code you've suggested such as in the calcTime method as it wouldn't accept List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> as a parameter. I've replaced this with QuerySnapshot and I can log the totalHours in the calcTime method to check that it's working correctly and not returning null, but I get a result of zero when it then tries to do hours.add(new PieEntry(calcTime(task.getResult()), "Self-Directed Learning")); For some reason it won't accept the calculation result as the first parameter in the pie chart ArrayList and I don't know why

Comment: Scrap that, I've just added pieChart.notifyDataSetChanged(); after my hours statement and this has worked! Thank you for your help